# Ipad Safari Plist MDM disable keyboard and group tabs

Tags: ios, ipad, plist, mdm, apple-business-manager

I tried to disable Safari's keyboard and the group tab 'feature' on supervised devices but I can find a proper way to do it.

Can you please advise what should be the best ways to do it?
Is there any documentation about the available configurations by Apple?

Thanks,
Gabor